# Spark Job status logging

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have a Spark code written in Scala where the only action is to save data back to Cassandra. Also we want to log the action start time, end time and status in another table to track it. For that need error handling. How can we do this logging with error message in another table when action is executed? For example is run is successful then will have status as Success and if failed then status as Failed with error message in another column.

Looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

**Oozie for final status of job failure/success**

You could use Oozie to schedule this Spark job.
It will use job status success or failed and pass it to next step in workflow as an argument.
Second step in Oozie workflow could be update database with final status.

**Other approaches to catching exceptions**

**catching any/first exception in processing action - use try-catch on driver** - put save action inside try-catch block.

This approach is described [here](http://rcardin.github.io/big-data/apache-spark/scala/programming/2016/09/25/try-again-apache-spark.html)
Especially "Asynchronous execution and exception handling" section cover that.

If you want to **catch all exceptions happening on every row in dataframe** you need to **use** something like **Accumulators or Scala Try** to gather all exceptions and aggregate them later.
More details [here](http://anishc.me/spark/exception-handling-spark-data-frames/)

**Task/Stage/Job progress use SparkListeners**

Progress could be updated from inside this job, there is no code in question so couldn't advice exactly where to put it.

Check [Spark Listeners](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-SparkListener.html) to get start and stop times of various parts of job execution and use that to update progress in database.

Regards,
Lukasz

Comment: Oozie is not an option for us. And we have to log the status in a separate table

Comment: What are using to scheduling / starting this job? Check Spark Listeners to storing start and stop times. https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-SparkListener.html

Comment: Our ask is simple. A DF is created and want to save it to Cassandra. Now need to log the start time, end time of that save in another table along with any exceptions occurred during save. So for one DF a single record will be created in table

Comment: try{} catch{} on driver code will catch all exceptions from execution.
So you may update database according whether there was exception or not.

Did you read article I pasted about SparkListener?
I think you mat use that for logging start and end time of a task - not sure exactly what metadata are available though on listener execution.

Comment: Try catch seems to be the correct solution. Can you post some sample code? Task level info we don't need to log

Comment: Try catch on driver follows what is described here
http://rcardin.github.io/big-data/apache-spark/scala/programming/2016/09/25/try-again-apache-spark.html
Especially "Asynchronous execution and exception handling" section

As you single action and you are interested in any exception in processing this action, in that case you can put save action inside try catch block.

If you want to track all exceptions happening on every row in dataframe you need to use something like Accumulators or Scala Try more details here
http://anishc.me/spark/exception-handling-spark-data-frames/

Comment: Any progress with that?